# Why is Windows throwing 404.4 errors for images?

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7

I just finished installing 2008 on a new server and enabled PHP support thru the Web PI Installer. I'm having two issues that I can't seem to get past.

I see modules, etc. but there doesn't appear to be a mapping for static files.

- GIF and PNG files are returning 404.4 errors (see below)
- Default files are configured but are not being returned (ex: index.php)

[image: 404.4 error]

[image: Mappings]

Comment: *something is jacked* isn't exactly much help

Comment: Just for the sake of argument, pretend that we can't see your computer's configuration from where we're all sitting, and that therefore "something is jacked" doesn't help us to help you. Have you reviewed http://support.microsoft.com/kb/942052/ ?

Comment: Looks like all mappings are gone. what's the correct choice from the popup for static?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've typically seen this when IIS isn't setup to serve static content. You need to add the Static Content role services when configuring the IIS role:

[image]

Check that, proceed to the end of the wizard, and that should be it. This will set up all appropriate handlers, etc.

Comment: I had to remove static as well as default document roles and then it worked as expected. Doing so did remove previous default mappings for index.php